# How to enable high-DPI mode in Gosu

Tags: ruby, graphics, dpi, libgosu

How can I enable High-DPI mode in Gosu? Also, how would I get the DPI to multiply coordinates by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosu does not include any DPI helpers right now. If you feel that it should, please file a GitHub issue.

The easiest way to make your game look good on HiDPI screens is to draw everything at @2x scale (regardless of what the screen DPI) and scale it down in `Window#draw` via `scale(0.5, 0.5) do <drawing code here> end`.